# Chaining promises but with different parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I previously used callbacks for all my nodejs functions that need to access mysql or txt files. This lead to ugly code stacking the callbacks inside of each other so I converted them to promises. How can I chain the promises but with different parameters each time?

I know how to chain them with `.then()`, but I don't know how to pass different arguments each time.

```
app.get('/visual', function (request, response) {
    loadTextFile('tables', function (measureList) {
         loadTextFile('roles', function (roleList) {
              // Do something with roleList and measureList
         });
    });
});
```

This is how my code looked before with the callbacks, how can I convert them to use `then()`? (I know how to convert loadTextFile to a promise.)

Comment: `ugly code stacking the callbacks inside of each other`, also called "callback hell" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an another alternative to callback hells and `Promise.then.then`, You could also use async/await for that :

```js
const loadTextFile = file => new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      // Fetch the files etc.
      resolve(data);
})

const loadFiles = async (request, response) => {
  const measureList = await loadTextFile('tables');
  const roleList = await loadTextFile('roles');

  // Do something with roleList and measureList

  response.send(finalData);
}

app.get('/visual', loadFiles);
```

Comment: I also considered that, but can I use this in app.get() {... ?

Comment: Do you have an example for that? I'm still kinda lost.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood. Ok, I have updated my answer, is it what you need?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks. Forgot that you can just put your function outside the app.get and just call it in there.

Comment: One more question, how do you handle errors from the promise when using await? Just try/catch?

Comment: Yes, exactly with try/catch. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Start using `async` - `await`:

```js
async function loadFiles() {
    const loadTextFilesTables = await loadTextFile('tables', measureList);
    const loadTextFilesRoles = await loadTextFile('roles', roleList);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Right but maybe worth explaining a little as I'm guessing the poster does not have experience with await / async?  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: I already read about that, I should have clarified that the calls are in an app.get(...) of a node server. How would I go about using it in there?

Answer (score 1):

As everybody else already said you should use [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) since the readability is superior to Promises / callbacks but i wanted to add that if your [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) doesn't depend on each other you can actually request them both simultaneity instead of waiting for one to finish before firing the next request using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
const loadTextFile = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const fileData = getFileData(file);
  resolve(data);
}

const loadFiles = async () => {
  const [measureList, roleList] = await Promise.all([
    loadTextFile('tables'),
    loadTextFile('roles')
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If what do you mean is like this :

```js
function multiply(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(a * a)
  })
}

function promise1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(5)
  })
}

promise1.then(add).then(res => console.log(res))
```

then the answer is yes.